# Expo android app is crashing after an ad update

Tags: android, crash, google-play, admob, expo

-SDK Version:42
-Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all):Android

-I have recently updated the app on google play with an ad.
-After the update, the app has been crashing at the start
-It works fine during expo start and even on android emulator
-but the google play bundle keeps on crashing.
I-Been trying to debug it but I am having trouble.
-Please any advice would be great.
-this is the app.js source sample:

```
enter code here

import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { StatusBar,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { AdMobInterstitial } from 'expo-ads-admob';


const adFunction = async() => {
  await AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID('ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712'); /*test ID*/
  await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync({ servePersonalizedAds: true});
  await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync();
 }



export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(adFunction,45000);},[]);


return (

<>  
<StatusBar backgroundColor="white" hidden ={true} />
 <WebView 
   style={styles.container}
   
   source={{ uri: 'https://xxj89098a8sdhjihjosad.net/' }} 
  />

 </>  ); 

 }

 '''
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your mainfest

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx" />
```

and provide your own
ca-app-pub

EDIT:

```
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx" />
</application></manifest>
```

Comment: "android": {
      
    "adaptiveIcon": {
      "foregroundImage": "./assets/xxyyx.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
    },
    "package": "com.xxyyx.xxyyx",
    "versionCode": 11,
    "permissions": [],
    "config": {
      
      "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxiiiixxiixiixi" 
      
    }
    
  
  }
  },     This is the app.json file which has the information you have mentioned. or is it different from editing the manifest metadata, which I believe requires ejecting my app?

Comment: you have to add it to your mainfest also

Comment: I have edited my answer above to where you should add your meta-data

Comment: <manifest package="expo.modules.application" xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <application> <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxyyyyyyyxxxxxxxxx" /> </application> </manifest> Thanks for your great support, I added this to under expo-application within node modules: The app still crashed when updated to google play and downloaded. Did I fix it in the right place or it could be an another issue?

Comment: iam not sure why u having trouble when update from google play and not also from the emulator . Sorry I can't help you

Comment: No problem still very appreciative of  your answer. I am just wondering if I put the metadata in the right androidmanifest.xml though.  There seems to be one in expo-application. expo-admob, expo-constants, and perhaps few others.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I just ended up removing admob all together from this app and it worked without it at that time.